# WMI query to select all printer paper size vb6

Tags: vb6, printing, wmi

please i need help in selecting all printer paper sizes with its name included in vb6. i already can select all printer using this code, and put it in a listbox.

```
Set WMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & Computer & "\root\cimv2")
Set Items = WMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer", , 48)
```

what i need is a code to select all paper size/names of a printer i select, and put it in another listbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WMI is an admin scripting service that applications should not rely on being present and running.  There are perfectly good ways to get the information directly though.

This is a sample Form with two ListBoxes:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const DC_PAPERNAMES = 16

Private Declare Function DeviceCapabilities Lib "winspool.drv" _
    Alias "DeviceCapabilitiesW" ( _
    ByVal lpDeviceName As Long, _
    ByVal lpPort As Long, _
    ByVal iIndex As Long, _
    ByVal lpOutput As Long, _
    ByVal lpDevMode As Long) As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim P As Printer

    For Each P In Printers
        lstPrinters.AddItem P.DeviceName
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub lstPrinters_Click()
    Dim P As Printer
    Dim lngPapers As Long
    Dim strPaperNames As String
    Dim lngPaper As Long
    Dim strPaperName As String
    Dim lngActualLength As Long

    Set P = Printers(lstPrinters.ListIndex)
    lngPapers = DeviceCapabilities(StrPtr(P.DeviceName), _
                                   StrPtr(P.Port), _
                                   DC_PAPERNAMES, _
                                   0, _
                                   0)
    strPaperNames = String$(lngPapers * 64, 0)
    lngPapers = DeviceCapabilities(StrPtr(P.DeviceName), _
                                   StrPtr(P.Port), _
                                   DC_PAPERNAMES, _
                                   StrPtr(strPaperNames), _
                                   0)
    lstPapers.Clear
    For lngPaper = 0 To lngPapers - 1
        strPaperName = Mid$(strPaperNames, 64 * lngPaper + 1, 64)
        lngActualLength = InStr(strPaperName, vbNullChar) - 1
        If lngActualLength > 1 Then strPaperName = Left$(strPaperName, lngActualLength)
        lstPapers.AddItem strPaperName
    Next
End Sub
```

You could also retrieve "paper size codes" or dimensions in millimeters using a similar call.  See [DeviceCapabilities Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183552%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Of course if you *want* to do this sort of thing from an admin script WMI would be the way to go.

Comment: your code ouput series of 1s for papersize, can you please help me get the actual size e.g paper size 1 is for `8-1/2 x 11`, i need to get this instead of the series of 1s

Answer (score 1):

Smith, you only need to access the `PaperSizesSupported` and/or `PaperTypesAvailable` properties of the [`Win32_Printer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) wmi class, both properties are arrays.

Comment: i already checked, and can't seem to figure out a way. if you can help me out, then i'll be grateful